# Is it possible to make FileReference.upload() block (In ActionScript 3.0)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am working on a Flash file upload widget, and I want it to upload one file at a time.  In my upload function, I currently have a `FileReferenceList`, and I am looping through it, calling `upload` on each one.  However, since `FileReference.upload` is non-blocking, all of the uploads are going simultaneously.

Is it possible to make the `uplaod` function block?  Or do I need to chain the uploads together, by registering an event to upload the next one when the first one's Event.COMPLETE event fires?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't generally do that with AS3, you have to manage the "asynchronous" requests through chaining.

I would usually have my list of files and upload one, catching the complete event and then do another.  Same principle applies for downloading or retrieving files with URLLoader.